# Where can I get Ropsten Eth?

Tags: ropsten

I want to create my own coin but I want to experiment first. I'm trying to deploy in the Eth wallet. All the websites to get Ropsten eth are down.How can I try making a coin without spending any money? Or do I need to? Is there a better way to deploy? I understand the code for the most part but I'd like to know how to run it and try things.

Ropsten address 
0x56212F540b4a1057cEBD6d10EE66D56a527CfCA2

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x56212F540b4a1057cEBD6d10EE66D56a527CfCA2

Comment: "All the websites to get Ropsten eth are down." Could you list the websites you tried?

Comment: I can't find all the links but tried a bunch still no eth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building your own token should be done locally first, on a simulated blockchain like [Ganache](https://www.codementor.io/swader/developing-for-ethereum-getting-started-with-ganache-l6abwh62j), or through a process such as this one [demoed with the Embark framework](https://bitfalls.com/2018/09/27/getting-started-with-embark-3-2-how-to-build-your-own-token/). You typically go to a "live testnet" like Ropsten, Rinkeby etc. only once you're happy with how things work locally on your own machine.

As far as Ropsten ether goes, though, this faucet works well: https://faucet.ropsten.be/ and this one: https://faucet.metamask.io/ - both will give you some REth to play with.

Answer (score 2):

You can load 1 Ether into a wallet at https://faucet.ropsten.be/.

It is restricted to one wallet per IP per day.

Comment: it has errors on site

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum [Ropsten testnet faucet](https://tx-test.net/faucet/ETH).

Comment: does not works at all

Answer (score 0):

FYI Testnets Ropsten, Rinkeby and Kovan have been deprecated. Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running b/c of the recent Ethereum Merge.

If you need any free Goerli testETH, this is one of the most-used faucets by web3 devs - https://goerlifaucet.com.

I can reliably get more Goerli testETH every day, which is usually enough for all my basic testnet needs.